External USB disk mounting failed
The external HDD worked fine up until a couple of days. Opened and stored some stuff in Ubuntu and later in Windows 11 too.
Now I get the following message:

Error mounting/dev/sda1 at/media/***/ TOSHIBA EXT: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other erroг

Lately energy service has been shutting down a lot, hence this has probably had an impact on my hardware.

You mention windows version (11) but not what Ubuntu product & release you're using?? For specific help I suggest you provide specifics.  In your place I'd NOT try and mount it until you've performed file-system checks, esp. after a power outage; as if problems are detected & fixed; normal mounting can be expected after that. The command to perform check/fixes varies on file-system details of which you gave no clear clues.

If the filesystem is ntfs, use ntfsfix, if it is ext4, use fsck.
